# How do I do a Get Request on a Hosted ISP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailgun

This question is going to seem rather vague, but that is possibly because I do not really understand what I need to do or how to go about it.

Mailgun has a way for users to get the response of emails sent using it's API and Webhooks.

[help.mailgun.com : How do webhooks work?](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/202236504-How-do-webhooks-work-)

I really do not understand how to get this to work.

I have a hosted ISP that we are sending emails from.

Obviously, I do not want to try to get the response immediately after sending the message from the webform because the responses could come days later.

Would this need to be a server installed component? If so, would I need to install a component via the ISP's Control Panel or would I be able to write something that would install it when run from Visual Studio?

There could be another name for what I'm doing. As it is now, I can't seem to find any results.

This website does NOT use MVC. Maybe one day.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, there are two ways to get feedback from Mailgun:
https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#tracking-messages

1. You can ask Mailgun if something has happened by **sending a request** to `api.mailgun.net` regularly. See example code here (select C# from the "Code sample preference" menu at the top): https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#events
   To use the code example, you need to include [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) in your project (for example through [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp)). You can probably also change the code a bit and use .NET's built-in `WebClient` instead.
2. You can also tell Mailgun to notify your site whenever something happens, using **webhooks**. Here, you need to create a separate page (.aspx/.ashx), and register the page's url in your Mailgun control panel. That page will then receive a POST request from time to time, which your code needs to parse.
   https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#webhooks

**Edit:**

Here is an example of a Mailgun webhook, where someone has created the page www.YOURDOMAINHERE.com/**sms.aspx**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8489098/1869660

The data which is sent from Mailgun can be found in `Request.Params`

- To find the parameters you're interested in, looks like you can use http://bin.mailgun.net/ for testing.
- Don't forget to validate the data to make sure it came from Mailgun. See "Securing Webhooks" in the documentation, and example code here: http://improve.dk/verifying-mailgun-webhooks/

*To make sure `ValidateRequest="false"` works in the example, look at this question: [ValidateRequest="false" doesn't work in Asp.Net 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4)*

Comment: What you are describing would require some sort of background service to be running on my ISP's server, querying Mailgun. I doubt an ISP will install a custom service like that.

Comment: I did see the documentation. I did not find any examples of how to write these webhooks, though.

Comment: #1: You're right, it may not be possible to do that fully automatically in your case. #2: I have added a webhook example.

Comment: This might be exactly what I need. It is a "on the side" project that I am doing for free (non-profit organization), so it might take me some time to get it working. I'll leave it "unaccepted as answer" for now, so that I can easily find it if I happen to close/lose this spot. :)

Comment: Alright, good luck :)